# Можно ли установить неподписанный .apk файл?

Tags: android, apk

Такой вопрос, можно ли установить неподписанный .apk файл, чтобы протестировать на своём телефоне до релиза в маркете? Или нужно, чтобы он обязательно был подписан?

Я пробовал установить не подписанный, но мне пишет "Приложение не установлено".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Кроме версии [[@ЮрийСПб](/users/17609/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B1)](/users/17609/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B1), еще возможны варианты:

1. На девайсе уже стоит прога с таким же пакетом, но подписанная другим ключом (обычно возникает такая коллизия, когда разработка ведется на нескольких компах и на каждом из компов генерируется свой debug ключ). Чтобы такого не возникало, имеет смысл расшаривать один и тот же debug ключ между всеми компами/участниками.
2. Если `android:versionCode` в манифесте ниже, чем тот, который уже стоит на девайсе, - это тоже потенциальная проблема. Установщик, правда, обычно только предупреждает о несоответствии версий приложения.
3. Если `minSdk` в манифесте указан выше, чем тот, который стоит в аппарате, система также может отказать в установке.
4. Если `<uses-feature>` тег в манифесте указывает на требуемые аппаратные возможности, которых нет в девайсе, - это тоже повод для отказа в установке.
5. Если используются NDK библиотеки, несовпадающие с целевой платформой, также возможны проблемы. Целевых платформ пока что 4: `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7`, `mips` и `x86` - 90% аппаратов это платформа `armeabi` - процессоры ARM v.6 - откройте APK и загляните в каталог lib - он должен быть либо пустой, либо должен содержать подкаталоги с названиями целевой платформы.
6. Возможна версия, что используется нестандартный установщик. В последнее время их развелось как грязи. Имеет смысл всегда пользоваться стоковым установщиком пакетов.

Comment: А как ключ расшарить на всех компах?

Comment: Скопировать файл: `<home>/.android/debug.keystore`

Answer (score 3):

Проверьте разрешено ли у вас на девайсе из непроверенных источников приложения ставить.

Это где-то в "Настройки-Безопасность".

Comment: отмечено, что разрешено

Comment: А приложение с таким же пакетом там, случаем, уже не стоит?

Comment: нет, вот вроде нашёл ответ http://hashcode.ru/questions/122442/android-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

в этом случае хотел спросить, вот, например, я сделал подписанный apk файл, чтобы протестировать на своём девайсе, потом при публикации в маркет нужно новым ключом подписывать, или можно оставить и со старым и заливать на маркет?

Comment: @Sting95, на девайс можно устанавливать apk, подписанный debug ключом. Выкладывать в Play Market - только release.